# Mean-variance portfolio probelm

Tags: optimization, random-variables, finance

So the question asks:

Consider three uncorrelated stocks in the market. Each stock has variance 1. The expected returns are given by $2, 3 $ and $ 5$ respectively. Find the optimal mean-variance portfolio min ($wCw^T-wm^T$) under the feasible portfolio constraint $w1 + w2 + w3 = 1$ and the ﬁxed risk constraint  $σ^2_V = 2$.

So so far I have : Let ri be the random variable associated with the rate of return for asset i, for i = 1, 2,3, and define the random vector $z=(2, 3, 5)^T$

Set µi = E(ri) and  µ1 = 2,  µ2 = 3,  µ3 = 5

$m = (2,3,5) ^T$ , and cov(z) = Σ.

If w = (w1, w2,w3)  then T is a set of weights associated with a portfolio, then the rate of return of this portfolio

r = Σ from i=1 to n  $r_i w_i$

is also a random variable with mean $m^Tw$ and variance $w^ TΣw$. In the Markowitz theory an optimal portfolio is any portfolio solving the following quadratic program:

M minimize $1 /2w^ TΣw $

subject to $m^Tw ≥ µb$, and $e^Tw = 1$

where e always denotes the vector of ones, i.e., each of the components of e is the number 1.

The KKT conditions for this quadratic program are :

0 = Σw − λm − γe (1)

µb ≤ $m ^Tw,$ $e^ T  w = 1$, 0 ≤ λ (2)

$λ^ T (m^Tw − µb) = 0 $ (3)

Are so far my solution right? But I really have no idea how to solve the system, I think the answer will be ($w,λ,γ$), right?